# JAVA get unit of measure and measurement from a string

Tags: java, string, extract

I have a string:

```
String = "2 ltr. btl., select   varieties when you buy 6 $1.25 ea.-50¢  MIX OR MATCH";
```

Is it possible to extract the unit of measurement from the given string? (2 ltr)

Note: the unit of measurement and measurement could appear anywhere in the string.

EDIT:
One of these keywords should appear

```
oz. oz lbs. lbs lb. lb kg. kg k g. g pk. pk ea. ea ml. ml pck. pck ct. ct qt. qt liter ltr ltr. fl oz fl oz.
```

I would like to get the unit of measurement and its corresponding measurement.

Comment: so what are the rules?  or is `when you` a valid measurement?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to post the rules.
When any of these keywords appear:
oz. oz lbs. lbs lb. lb kg. kg k g. g pk. pk ea. ea ml. ml pck. pck ct. ct qt. qt liter ltr ltr. fl oz fl oz.
I would like to get the unit of measurement at its corresponding measurement.

Comment: so some regex of numeric input followed by space followed by one of any of the keywords?

Comment: Try [`String pat = "(\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\s*((?:fl\\s*)?oz\\.?|lb(?:s\\.?)?|k(?:g\\.?)?|g\\.?|pc?k\\.?|ea\\.?|ml\\.?|ct\\.?|qt\\.?|l(?:iter|tr)\\.?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/eR3kC9/3).

Comment: Better: [`String pat = "(\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\s*((?:(?:fl\\s*)?oz|g|pc?k|ea|ml|[qc]t|l(?:iter|tr))(?:\\.|\\b)|lb(?:s(?:\\.|\\b))?|k(?:g(?:\\.|\b))?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/eR3kC9/6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex to extract the amount (with optional decimal part) and its measure unit is:

```
(?x)\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+
  (?:
     (?:fl )?oz(?:\.|\b)|lbs?(?:\.|\b)|kg(?:\.|\b)|kg?\b|g(?:\.|\b)
   | pc?k(?:\.|\b)|ea(?:\.|\b)|ml(?:\.|\b)|[cq]t(?:\.|\b)
   | liter\b|ltr(?:\.|\b)
  )
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uZ7yZ6/4

Corresponding Java code:

```
String input = "2 ltr. btl., select   varieties when you buy 6 $1.25 ea.-50¢  MIX OR MATCH";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
      "(?x)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s+"
    + "  (?:"
    + "     (?:fl )?oz(?:\\.|\\b)|lbs?(?:\\.|\\b)|kg(?:\\.|\\b)|kg?\\b|g(?:\\.|\\b)"
    + "   | pc?k(?:\\.|\\b)|ea(?:\\.|\\b)|ml(?:\\.|\\b)|[cq]t(?:\\.|\\b)"
    + "   | liter\\b|ltr(?:\\.|\\b)"
    + "  )"
);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

https://ideone.com/pGDVVm

Comment: The current expression will also match `2 g` in `2 girls`

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed your `(?:\.|\b)` change, which I consider crucial. You're absolutely right! Missed this point myself

Comment: Also, mind if i ask if it's possible to skip if it's found at the start of the string?

Comment: If you need only the first occurrence of the pattern, just change the `while (matcher.find()) {...}` to `if (matcher.find()) {...}`